# How to call a modal thickbox from a modal dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, thickbox

In my case i am calling a thickbox from a modal dialog box, in that thick box i have loaded some contents and the problem is when i try to enter something on the thickbox window or try to press enter key then it will focus out to its parent window , how can i overcome this 
?

i mean i need the particular thickbox a modal

i have tried the below method  in url

```
(TB_inline?height=155&width=300&inlineId=hiddenModalContent&modal=true)
```

but does not seems working

Please help me to solve this issue.